# Constructor Function: How can I tell which function is the constructor?

Tags: solidity, constructor

How can I tell which function is the constructor function?

In the OpenZeppelin implementation of the [MultisigWallet](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.2.0/contracts/MultisigWallet.sol), OpenZeppelin claims this is the constructor function:

```
/**
   * Constructor, sets the owners addresses, number of approvals 
     required, and daily spending limit
   * @param _owners A list of owners.
   * @param _required The amount required for a transaction to be 
     approved.
   */

function MultisigWallet(address[] _owners, uint256 _required, uint256 _daylimit)
    Shareable(_owners, _required)
    DayLimit(_daylimit) { }
```

My problem is that I cannot tell the difference between this function and any other function.

How do I identify constructor functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older contracts, constructors will be a function with the same name as the contract they're in. In newer contracts, the constructor will be labeled as `constructor` in place of `function ContractName`.

Comment: Is there any reason this constructor function does not have a {} after the parameters?

Comment: The lines following the parameters, `Shareable(_owners, _required)` and `DayLimit(_daylimit)`, are the super constructors. Those are calling the constructors of parents when you call the `MultisigWallet` constructor. The brackets after the `DayLimit(_daylimit)` are the ones where you would put code to execute in the constructor.